# Function not getting called when Angular controller runs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have a controller, CardsCtrl, that displays a list of cards. The list of cards is populated with a call to the Cards service. Like so:

```
// In CardsCtrl:
$scope.cards = Cards.forUser(currentAuth.uid);
```

This works fine under the simple use case of logging in and seeing my list of cards. The issue is that if User1 logs OUT (which is triggered by a call to `$firebaseAuth(rootRef).$unauth())` and then User2 logs IN, User2 sees User1's list of cards!

Somehow, `$scope.cards` is NOT calling the `Cards.forUser()` function with User2's ID and is instead just going off of the old $scope.cards value.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was able to fix this by putting a simple

```
$scope.cards = [];
```

Above my other call. So my code looks like this:

```
$scope.cards = [];

$scope.cards = Cards.forUser(currentAuth.uid);
```